# Calling same function in multiple object's context?

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

I have an object structure like so;

```
{
   this.parent = undefined;
   this.children = [];
}
```

All values in `children` have the same structure as above except that their `parent` would be would a reference to the object that has it as its child.

How can I easily iterate over all children of children etc but in the child's object context?

I know how I can loop the children for one object

```
obj.children.forEach(function(child) {

});
```

But how can I iterate all children of children, when the children could be into 10-20-30 deep heirachy?

Comment: You must use a `recursive` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

```
function deepForEach(node, fn) {
    fn(node);
    node.children.forEach(function(child) {
        deepForEach(child, fn);
    });
}

deepForEach(obj, function(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

The way this works becomes evident if we state it in plain English:

- If there are no children, just call the callback with the node. *(base case)*
- If there are children, first deal with ourself, and then do this whole procedure for each child.

This type of recursion is called [preorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order).

Comment: Could you please explain what is happening here please?

Answer (score 1):

We will write a recursive function. **Recursive** means that it will execute itself again:

```
function iterate(obj) {
    // we will write the parent and the name
    console.log(obj.parent + ' | ' + obj.name);

    // if it has children
    if (obj.children.length) {
        // for each child
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.children.length; i < l; i++) {
            // we will call this function again
            arguments.callee(obj.children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if we have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'P1',
    parent: undefined,
    children: [
        {
            name: 'P2',
            parent: 'P1',
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'P3',
            parent: 'P1',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'P4',
                    parent: 'P3',
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'P5',
                            parent: 'P4',
                            children: []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'P6',
            parent: 'P1',
            children: []
        }
    ]
};
```

We can iterate all over it:

```
iterate(obj);
```

<kbd>**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/gLubz/)**</kbd> (open your console in browser)

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use recurson like icktoofay is suggesting.

Something that is a little more annoying in this kind of processing is how to manage traversal in "chunks" (e.g. if you want to do this in "background" in a javascript program using a timer).

In this case you can use an explicit stack:

```
function process_tree(root_node,
                      process_node,
                      chunk_size,
                      completion_call)
{
    var todo = []; // nodes that need processing

    function processOneChunk() {
        for (var j=0; todo.length && j<chunk_size; j++) {
            var x = todo.pop();
            process_node(x);
            for (var i=0; i<x.children.length; i++) {
                todo.push(x.children[i]);
            }
        }
        if (todo.length) {
            setTimeout(processOneChunk, 0);
        } else {
            completion_call();
        }
    }

    todo.push(root_node);
    setTimeout(processOneChunk, 0);
}
```